# Magento: Bypass Checkout for Free Products

Tags: checkout, downloadable

I'm triying to create a new module to bypass checkout process for free downloadable products. As I'm not a developer I need some help with xml files of module.

I've this folder structure:

```
app/etc/modules/Fe_Freecheckout.xml

app/code/local/Fe/Freecheckout/controllers/CheckoutController.php app/code/local/Fe/Freecheckout/etc/config.xml
```

And these are the contents of files:

CheckoutController.php

```
<?php
public function purchaseAction() {
if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirectUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl().'customer/account');
        return;
 }
 $request = $this->getRequest();
 $id = $request->getParam('id');
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->load($id)
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
 if(!($product->getIsVirtual() && $product->getFinalPrice() == 0)){
     Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($this->__('Method only available for Free Downloadable Items'));
     return $this;
 }
 $onepage = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
 /* @var $onepage Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage */
 try{
     $quote = $onepage->getQuote();
     /* @var $quote Mage_Sales_Model_Quote */
     $quote->addProduct($product);
     Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
     $onepage->initCheckout();
     $payment=array('method'=>'free');
     $onepage->savePayment($payment);   
     $onepage->saveOrder();
     $this->getResponse()->setRedirect('/downloadable/customer/products');
 }
 catch(Exception $e){
     $result = $e->getMessage();
     Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($result);
 }
 }
 ?>
```

app/etc/modules/Fe_Freecheckout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fe_Freecheckout>

            <!-- Whether our module is active: true or false -->
            <active>true</active>

            <!-- Which code pool to use: core, community or local -->
            <codePool>local</codePool>

        </Fe_Freecheckout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And this is app/code/local/Fe/Freecheckout/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Fe_Freecheckout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Fe_Freecheckout>
    </modules>

    <global>
    <rewrite>        
        <Fe_Freecheckout_checkout_onepagecontroller>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/onepage/#]]></from> <!-- Mage_Checkout_OnepageController  -->
            <to>/Freecheckout/checkout_onepage/</to> <!-- Package_ModuleName_Checkout_OnepageController  -->
        </Fe_Freecheckout_checkout_onepagecontroller>
    </rewrite>
</global>
</config>
```

Then in product/view.phtml I use the following code to checkout:

```
<?php if($_product->isVirtual() && $_product->getFinalPrice()==0) { ?>
                <a href="/Freecheckout/checkout/purchase/id/<?php echo $_product->getId()?>"><?php echo $this->__('Download and Install') ?></a>
            <?php } ?>
```

I always get a Page not Found. Any directions, please?

Answer (score 0):

To make a start, can you modify the `config.xml` file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Fe_Freecheckout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Fe_Freecheckout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <rewrite>        
            <fe_freecheckout>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/onepage/#]]></from> <!-- Mage_Checkout_OnepageController  -->
                <to><![CDATA[/freecheckout/checkout/purchase/]]></to> <!-- Package_ModuleName_Checkout_OnepageController  -->
            </fe_freecheckout>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <fe_freecheckout>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                   <module>Fe_FreeCheckout</module>
                   <frontName>freecheckout</frontName>
               </args>
           </fe_freecheckout>   
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Are your sure `CheckoutController.php` looks like how you have posted above? I am not seeing the `class Fe_FreeCheckout_CheckoutController` declaration. It must look like below:

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage'. DS .'Checkout'. DS .'controllers'. DS .'OnepageController.php';
class Fe_FreeCheckout_CheckoutController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{
    public function purchaseAction()
    {
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
        {
            $this->_redirectUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl().'customer/account');
            return;
        }
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $id = $request->getParam('id');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                     ->load($id)
                     ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        if(!($product->getIsVirtual() && $product->getFinalPrice() == 0))
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($this->__('Method only available for Free Downloadable Items'));
            return $this;
        }
        $onepage = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
        /* @var $onepage Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage */
        try
        {
           $quote = $onepage->getQuote();
           /* @var $quote Mage_Sales_Model_Quote */
           $quote->addProduct($product);
           Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
           $onepage->initCheckout();
           $payment=array('method'=>'free');
           $onepage->savePayment($payment);   
           $onepage->saveOrder();
           $this->getResponse()->setRedirect('/downloadable/customer/products');
         } catch(Exception $e) {
              $result = $e->getMessage();
              Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($result);
         }
     }
}
```

**Step 1:**
After these modifications, try to run the URL: `http://{yourdomain/localhost}/freecheckout/checkout/purchase`.

**Step 2:**
After trying the URL directly, (if it works), run the URL:
`http://{yourdomain/localhost}/checkout/onepage`, to check if its redirecting to the above mentioned URL.

Try the above code and steps and let me know if it works for you.

Happy Coding....